# How Rearrange Screenshots on Google Play

Tags: android, screenshot, google-play

In Google Play I have uploaded screenshots for Phones, 7- and 10-inch tablets. I am aware about that its going to pick screenshots that will best suit on the user's device, it will order according to user device, I have tried that and all works fine on device.

But What about web store ? (https://play.google.com/) Why its always showing 10-inch tablets screenshots first ?

on web store I want do show phone screenshot first then 7- and 10-inch tablets, is there any way to put all theses screenshots in specific order?

Comment: Why the close vote ? Its a valid question

Comment: I don't think there is a way to rearrange screenshots for when a user is visiting your app page on the Play Store through a web browser. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news 

Answer (score 2):

This article https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en&ref_topic=2897459 states in the screenshots section:

> On the Google Play web store (play.google.com), tablet screenshots are prioritized and appear before phone screenshots.

So there is apparently no way of reordering the screenshots, and the tablets will appear first on a desktop browser.